# Stanford C++ lib Missing Vector.cpp and Map.cpp

Tags: c++, vector

Hello i just enroll stanford CS106B and got a huge problem . The assignment need Vector and Map but seem like the library is missing each of them.

And i didn't know where to download Vector.cpp and Map.cpp .
  Does the course only available for paid students ???  thanks.

http://imageshack.com/a/img28/6127/x97d.png

Hello, i just download Hello World starter file and still got missing message.

"no member name "put" , no member name "containsKey"  ,etc

Comment: If you are using alternative implementations of map and vector, you need to remove 'using namespace std' from your code, or they will alias to the std versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the materials Stanford offers in CS106B/X are available to download for free. For example, here's [a blank "Hello, World!" project from Fall 2016 offering of CS106B](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b//assnFiles/Blank.zip) that should come bundled with all the Stanford libraries.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The given link is broken.

Comment: @oya163 Fixed with a permanent link!